# QGIS - stacked bar - color stacked bars according to numerical value

Tags: qgis, diagram

I have a point file with the following structure:
name; x; y; Value year one; Value year two; ...

From this I could generate stacked bars without any problems. The size of the individual bars is displayed depending on the corresponding numerical value. However, the bars should all be the same size and only the color should be defined according to the numerical value.
I'm using QGIS 3.28.5 and win 11.